# Getting error in local database app

Tags: ios

Any one help me. I getting **error:**

> 2016-05-05 15:54:54.688 DemoApp[917:239962] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'There
>   doesn't seem to be a valid compiled storyboard at path
>   '/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/A803DBD5-0B64-4854-A8E6-5717E4C1F1EF/DemoApp.app/Base.lproj/Main.storyboardc''
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x23bb410b 0x2335ae17 0x283d9221 0x14941d 0x1142d3 0x27d286cd 0x27d28659 0x27d1064f 0x27d27fb5 0x27ce2275
>   0x23b76f59 0x23b7525d 0x23b7568f 0x23ac8bf9 0x23ac89e5 0x24d14ac9
>   0x27d58ba1 0x14e865 0x23777873) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: try to remove derived data and and build again.

Comment: i try delete app and reinstall. But no solution.

Comment: not delete app , xcode Window (from top ) > projects > select project , There is option for delete derived data .

Comment: i try it. but getting same error.

Comment: did you use any git for merge ? Because it seems like error in storyboard xml . Right click on storyboard and open as source code. This might show error .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111116/discussion-between-keyur-and-mohammad-ishaq).